# Redirect output from silent SQL Server installation to Standard Error in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/CONFIGURATIONFILE=Config.ini";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

p.Start();

string line;
while ((line = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   tOutputStandard.Text += line + "\r\n";
}

while ((line = p.StandardError.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   tOutputError.Text += line + "\r\n";
}

p.WaitForExit();
```

The configuration file is set to run silently.
tOutputStandard and tOutputError are TextBox's that will show the output.

However it doesn't show any output from the SQL Server installation.  I have tried running other applications, and they send the output correctly, so I don't think the code is at fault.

How can I get SQL Server to pipe it's output to C#?
I need to know what the error is if installation fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that the real cause to this problem, is that the SQL installation won't output anything if run directly from the MSI.

Instead, you have to first run the MSI, and extract it to a temp directory, and then run the setup exe in that directory.  This exe will give you the output you desire.

The answer as posted by Markus Safar with event handlers may also help for other needs.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps. Delete your following code fragment:

```
string line;
while ((line = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   tOutputStandard.Text += line + "\r\n";
}

while ((line = p.StandardError.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   tOutputError.Text += line + "\r\n";
}
```

Connect to the event handlers OutputDataReceived and ErrorDataReceived instead:

```
p.OutputDataReceived += this.OutputDataReceived;
p.ErrorDataReceived += this.ErrorDataReceived;
```

The callback methods look like this.

```
private void ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    tOutputError.Text += e.Data + "\r\n";
}

private void OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    tOutputStandard.Text += e.Data + "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all.  Also, you can't just update from non GUI thread, so I don't know how you expect this to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the pipe working you can always just read the install log file.

I also use silent installs via Powershell.
For errors I look through the Setup Bootstrap log folders fro the latest folder and loop through the Details.txt file for lines containing "Error"

```
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\<datestamp>\Details.txt
```

Not perfect, but better than no output at all.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a bit temperamental and is going to break if the version changes.  Also, you can just get this output by using stdout.